# Variable access syntax issue

Tags: tcl

In the code below, I am getting an error while accessing `${data_${k}_store}`.   Can anyone help me with the proper syntax?

> Error: can't read "data_${k": no such variable    Use error_info for
>   more info. (CMD-013)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nY6hk.png)

Comment: Please post your code examples so we are able to copy them. Refer to: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: set array "" ;
set array [add_to_collection $array [get_cells  cell1] ] ;
set array [add_to_collection $array [get_cells cell2 ] ] ;
set array [add_to_collection $array [get_cells cell3] ] ; 

set k 0;
foreach_in_collection fifo_inst $array {
set data_${k}_store [get_pins -of_objects [get_nets $fifo_inst/fifo*]]
report_timing  -from clk1        -through ${data_${k}_store} -delay_type min_max -slack_lesser_than 2 -nworst 100 > $rpt_base.launch_seq_idata_${k}
incr k;
}


Error: can't read "data_${k": no such variable
 Use error_info for more info. (CMD-013)

Comment: I have added the image file as well

Answer (score 2):

Usually, when you've got a complex name like that you're better off making an *alias* to it using `upvar` so that you can manipulate it with a simple name:

```
# The ‘0’ is for “current stack level”
upvar 0 data_${k}_store datastore
# Now any operation on ‘datastore’ is forwarded to data_${k}_store
puts $datastore
```

Comment: Cool - that's a really useful usage of upvar!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you're trying to reference a variable whose name itself is actually dynamic, and because you are using curly brackets the inner ${k} doesn't get evaluated. So instead of this

```
${data_${k}_store}
```

try this

```
[set data_${k}_store]
```